# UIButton Animation issue - iOS 7

Tags: ios

I am using iOS 7. I had use button on scroll view. and I am also use Touch down and Touch up inside Methods for `UIButton`. 
Now in iOS 7 while i am scroll the next page Touch Down Method called every time and page can't scroll. 
This issue occurs only in iOS 7 and specific in iPad not in iPod Touch and iPhone.

Comment: can you add some code

Comment: UIButton is more sensitive in iOS 7 as Compare to iOS 6.

Comment: What should i do? please give me a proper solution.

Comment: Hi, I had Find my problem. iOS 7 Provide Multitasking Gesture. So in Setting Screen i had disable it. But i have to disable from my app.So u have any idea to disable it in our app.

Comment: [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];                                     This Method not work in iPad iOS7 because it provides Multitasking For Switch between Two Apps. Do u any Solution????